# How to get audio data from rtp packet...?

Tags: c#, .net, rtp, pcap.net

I'm using .net to do call recroding with pcap.net.

till now I have got the rtp packet. And its length is 32 bytes.

The codec used is G729 and payload type is 18.

```
byte[] bytes = HexString2Bytes(udp.Payload.ToHexadecimalString());          
string rtppayload = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

I need to get the actual rtp payload.
 Plz help me...

Comment: Why do you use ASCII? Does RTP uses ASCII encoding to encode the data?

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake. Only udp.Payload.ToHexadecimalString() was enough. No ascii encoding is required.

Answer (score 1):

**I have got the voice from rtp packets.**

what i have done is that, converted the last 20 bytes of the rtp payload to byte array, then written into a file of raw format.

then done the following steps....

1. converted the raw file to pcm file by g729 decoder.
   (downloaded from [www.voiceage.com/openinit_g729.php](http://www.voiceage.com/openinit_g729.php)
2. imported that pcm file to audacity like , import->raw data.
3. then played the voice.
4. exported as wav format.